# CONTEXT_INFO() and CONVERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In an attempt to build example code for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615284/sql-server-get-inserted-record-identity-value-when-using-a-views-instead-of-tr) question, I ran into a problem with `CONTEXT_INFO()`.

What I'm doing is converting an int to varbinary(128) so I can pass that to `SET CONTEXT_INFO`. I can convert the varbinary back to int before I do the SET, but after I SET and then GET, the CONVERT always returns zero even though the varbinary value is clearly not zero.

Binary is not my strong suit, so I'm probably missing something simple.

#### Code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
USE tempdb
GO

DECLARE @number         int
DECLARE @ContextInfo    varbinary(128)

SET @number =  16777216

SET @ContextInfo = CONVERT(varbinary(128), @number)

SELECT @number                     AS [@number]
SELECT @ContextInfo                AS [@ContextInfo]
SELECT CONVERT(int, @ContextInfo)  AS [CONVERT(int, @ContextInfo)]

SET CONTEXT_INFO @ContextInfo
GO

SELECT CONTEXT_INFO()               AS [CONTEXT_INFO()]
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONTEXT_INFO()) AS [CONVERT(int, CONTEXT_INFO()) (Zero)]
GO

DECLARE @ContextInfo    varbinary(128)

SET @ContextInfo = CONTEXT_INFO()

SELECT @ContextInfo                 AS [@ContextInfo]
SELECT CONVERT(int, @ContextInfo)   AS [CONVERT(int, @ContextInfo)   (Zero)]
GO
```

#### Result

```
    @number
-----------
   16777216

@ContextInfo
-----------------------------------
0x01000000

CONVERT(int, @ContextInfo)
--------------------------
                  16777216

CONTEXT_INFO()
-----------------------------------
0x0100000000000000[... more zeroes]

CONVERT(int, CONTEXT_INFO()) (Zero)
-----------------------------------
                                  0

@ContextInfo
-----------------------------------
0x0100000000000000[... more zeroes]

CONVERT(int, @ContextInfo)   (Zero)
-----------------------------------
                                  0
```

Whether I try to convert it directly from `CONTEXT_INFO()` or write `CONTEXT_INFO()` to a variable, the result of `CONVERT` is zero.

Edit: Fixed link text

---

### Conversion Example

This example shows how an int converted to varbinary(128) will convert back without an issue, but CONTEXT_INFO() fails the conversion.

(This is for the ongoing conversation with Andomar.)

### Test

```
DECLARE @int        int
DECLARE @varBin128  varbinary(128)

SET @int = 1

SET @varBin128 = CONVERT(varbinary(128), @int)
SET CONTEXT_INFO @varBin128

SELECT CONVERT(int, @varBin128)     AS [Convert @varBin128)]
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONTEXT_INFO()) AS [Convert once]
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(4), CONTEXT_INFO())) AS [Convert twice]
```

### Results

```
Convert @varBin128)
-------------------
                  1

Convert once
------------
           0

Convert twice
-------------
            1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A varbinary(128) is a 128 byte block of memory.  An int is a 4 byte block of memory.  So you can recover the int like this:

```
select convert(int,convert(varbinary(4),CONTEXT_INFO()))
```

The var in varbinary means the actual length varies, the number in parenthesis merely specifies the maximum size.  So this SELECT statement displays a 4-byte varbinary:

```
select convert(varbinary(128), 1)
```

But when you cast CONTEXT_INFO() to a varbinary(128), you really get a 128 byte varbinary.  This example is a nice demonstration:

```
set context_info 1
select convert(int,convert(varbinary(5),context_info()))
```

This will print 256; the last 3 bytes of the integer 1, with a 0 byte appended.

Comment: That worked! But why does the first part of the test script work? There, I'm doing a CONVERT to varbinary(128) and then converting it back. That works fine.

Comment: As you can see from your second select statement, CONVERT(varbinary(128),1) actually returns a 4 byte block.  Converting that back to a 4 byte int works fine.

Comment: See my example code appended above. The varbinary(128) that comes from CONTEXT_INFO() acts differently than a varbinary(128) variable.

Comment: Well, "CONVERT(varbinary(128), @int)" is actually a *4* byte varbinary(128).  When you pass it through CONTEXT_INFO, you end up with a *128* byte varbinary(128).  The length of the varbinary is lost in translation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still not sure that the "4 byte varbinary(128)" makes sense, but I see the affects.

Comment: Andomar, sorry for "unaccepting" your answer, but there is more to it so I wrote it up myself. I'm sure I've broken some basic rule netiquette.

Comment: No problem.  Binary works because it has only one length; varbinary has a length and a maximum length.  So of course binary passes through CONTEXT_INFO without loss.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it. [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) works with binary so we don't need any intermediate conversions (to varbinary(4)):

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 12345

SELECT
    CONTEXT_INFO(),
    CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS int),                    --zero
    /*CAST(LEFT(CONTEXT_INFO(), 4) AS int),*/       --fails
    CAST(SUBSTRING(CONTEXT_INFO(), 1, 4) AS int)    --works
```

Note: [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) does not work well with binary and fails with a conversion error

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to be a combination of the recommendations from Andomar and gbn and a recommendation from one of my colleagues.

If you use binary(128) instead of varbinary(128), everything is simpler.

### Query

```
--<< ====================================================
--<< varbinary
--<< ====================================================
DECLARE @varbin128 varbinary(128)

SET @varbin128 = CONVERT(varbinary(128), 12345)
SET CONTEXT_INFO @varbin128
SELECT
    @varbin128                                          AS [@varbin128],
    CONTEXT_INFO()                                      AS [CONTEXT_INFO()],
    CONVERT(int, @varbin128)                            AS [Convert (@varbin128)],
    CONVERT(int, CONTEXT_INFO())                        AS [Convert (CONTEXT_INFO())],
    CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary(4), CONTEXT_INFO())) AS [Convert(x2) (CONTEXT_INFO())]

--<< ====================================================
--<< binary
--<< ====================================================
DECLARE @bin128 binary(128)

SET @bin128 = CONVERT(binary(128), 12345)
SET CONTEXT_INFO @bin128
SELECT
    @bin128                                             AS [@bin128],
    CONTEXT_INFO()                                      AS [CONTEXT_INFO()],
    CONVERT(int, @bin128)                               AS [Convert (@bin128)],
    CONVERT(int, CONTEXT_INFO())                        AS [Convert (CONTEXT_INFO())],
    CONVERT(int, CONVERT(binary(4), CONTEXT_INFO()))    AS [Convert(x2) (CONTEXT_INFO())]
```

### Results

```
@varbin128 CONTEXT_INFO()   Convert (@varbin128) Convert (CONTEXT_INFO()) Convert(x2) (CONTEXT_INFO())
---------- ---------------- -------------------- ------------------------ ----------------------------
0x00003039 0x00003039000...                12345                        0                        12345

@bin128         CONTEXT_INFO()  Convert (@bin128) Convert (CONTEXT_INFO()) Convert(x2) (CONTEXT_INFO())
--------------- --------------- ----------------- ------------------------ ----------------------------
0x000...0003039 0x000...0003039             12345                    12345                            0
```

So, there *are* ways to make the convert work if you pass in a varbinary(128) value, but it requires a double-CONVERT. If you pass in a binary(128) value, it requires only a single CONVERT.